# Multithreaded generic matrices addition very slow when using custom classes

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I implemented the addition of two generic matrices using multithreading and a sequential algorithm. I tested my program with two big matrices (2000x2000) that contained real numbers (doubles) and the results were very good. The operation managed to finish very fast. Later I implemented a class that represents a complex number and tried to repeat the same scenario with two matrices and I found that it takes ages to finish the whole process even for two 50x50 matrices. What should I do in order to improve the duration of the execution?

This is the method that creates the threads(first of all I create two unidimensional arrays to be easier to provide each thread with its starting and ending point):

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
Matrix<T> *calculateLinearDistribution(Matrix<T> *matrix1,
                                       Matrix<T> *matrix2,
                                       Func operation,
                                       int nThreads) {
    const int n = matrix1->getN(), m = matrix2->getM(), totalNumbers = n * m;
    Matrix<T> *result = new Matrix<T>(n, m);
    T *matrix1Unidim = new T[totalNumbers];
    T *matrix2Unidim = new T[totalNumbers];
    convertMatrixToUnidimensionalArray(matrix1, matrix1Unidim);
    convertMatrixToUnidimensionalArray(matrix1, matrix2Unidim);
    if (totalNumbers < nThreads) {
        nThreads = totalNumbers;
    }
    const int quantityPerThread = totalNumbers / nThreads;
    int rest = totalNumbers % nThreads;
    int start = 0, end = 0;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::chrono::milliseconds startTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        end += quantityPerThread;
        if (rest > 0) {
            end++;
            rest--;
        }
        threads.push_back(std::thread(MultithreadedMethods<T, Func>::linearElementsDistribution, &matrix1Unidim[0],
                                      &matrix2Unidim[0], result, start, end, operation));
        start = end;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    std::chrono::milliseconds endTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    std::ofstream out(linearElemensStatisticsFile, std::ios_base::app);
    std::chrono::milliseconds time = endTime - startTime;
    out << "Dimensiune matrice: " << matrix1->getN() << "x" << matrix1->getM()
        << " | Nr. threads: " << nThreads << " | Timp de executie: " << time.count() << std::endl;
    out.close();
    delete[] matrix1Unidim;
    delete[] matrix2Unidim;
    return result;
}
```

This is the function provided to the thread:

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
void MultithreadedMethods<T, Func>::linearElementsDistribution(T *matrix1,
                                                               T *matrix2,
                                                               Matrix<T> *result,
                                                               int start,
                                                               int end,
                                                               Func operation) {
    const int m = result->getM();
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        result->getElements()[i / m][i % m] = operation(matrix1[i], matrix2[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is the point where I run the process with real numbers (it's very fast):

```
Matrix<double> *linearDistributionResult = calculateLinearDistribution(matrix1,
                                                                               matrix2,
                                                                               [](double a, double b) {
                                                                                   return a +
                                                                                          b;
                                                                               }, nThreads);
```

And finally this is the bad part where I try to use Complex Numbers and it takes a lot of time and even fails compared to the sequential result...

```
Matrix<ComplexNumber> *linearDistributionResult = calculateLinearDistribution(matrix1,
                                                                                          matrix2,
                                                                                          [](ComplexNumber a,
                                                                                             ComplexNumber b) {
                                                                                              return ComplexNumber(
                                                                                                      a.getRealComponent() +
                                                                                                      b.getRealComponent(),
                                                                                                      a.getImaginaryComponent() +
                                                                                                      b.getImaginaryComponent());
                                                                                          }, nThreads);
```

Of course this is the sequential implementation (I would like to point out that this is also very slow when I use Complex Numbers compared to real numbers):

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
Matrix<T> *calculateSequentialResult(Matrix<T> *matrix1,
                                     Matrix<T> *matrix2,
                                     Func operation) {
    const int n = matrix1->getN(), m = matrix1->getM();
    Matrix<T> *result = new Matrix<T>(n, m);
    std::chrono::milliseconds startTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            result->getElements()[i][j] = operation(matrix1->getElements()[i][j], matrix2->getElements()[i][j]);
        }
    }
    std::chrono::milliseconds endTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    std::ofstream out(sequentialElementsStatistics, std::ios_base::app);
    std::chrono::milliseconds time = endTime - startTime;
    out << "Dimensiune matrice: " << matrix1->getN() << "x" << matrix1->getM()
        << " | Nr. threads: 1 | Timp de executie: " << time.count() << std::endl;
    out.close();
    return result;
}
```

UPDATE
This is the result when using Very Sleepy To analyse the execution:
[image]

ComplexNumber class:

```
   class ComplexNumber {
    private:
        double realComponent;
        double imaginaryComponent;
    
    public:
    
        ComplexNumber() {}
    
        ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber &complexNumber);
    
        double getRealComponent() const;
    
        ComplexNumber(double realComponent, double imaginaryComponent);
    
        void setRealComponent(double realComponent);
    
        double getImaginaryComponent() const;
    
        void setImaginaryComponent(double imaginaryComponent);
    
        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const ComplexNumber &complexNumber);
    };

and the definition:

double ComplexNumber::getRealComponent() const {
    return realComponent;
}

void ComplexNumber::setRealComponent(double realComponent) {
    ComplexNumber::realComponent = realComponent;
}

double ComplexNumber::getImaginaryComponent() const {
    return imaginaryComponent;
}

void ComplexNumber::setImaginaryComponent(double imaginaryComponent) {
    ComplexNumber::imaginaryComponent = imaginaryComponent;
}

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(double realComponent, double imaginaryComponent) : realComponent(realComponent),
                                                                                imaginaryComponent(imaginaryComponent) {

}

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber &complexNumber) {
    this->imaginaryComponent = complexNumber.imaginaryComponent;
    this->realComponent = complexNumber.realComponent;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const ComplexNumber &complexNumber) {
    if (complexNumber.imaginaryComponent == 0) {
        os << std::to_string(complexNumber.realComponent);
    } else if (complexNumber.realComponent == 0) {
        os << std::to_string(complexNumber.imaginaryComponent) + "i";
    } else
        os << std::to_string(complexNumber.realComponent) + ((complexNumber.imaginaryComponent < 0) ?
                                                             ("-" + std::to_string(complexNumber.imaginaryComponent) +
                                                              "i") :
                                                             ("+" + std::to_string(complexNumber.imaginaryComponent) +
                                                              "i"));
    return os;
}
```

---

## Solved

The problem was that I used regex to parse the complex numbers from the file, and they were very slow. After replacing them I managed to get the correct behaviour.

Comment: This question is better suited for the CodeReview site.

Comment: did you try to pass code profiler to find any hotspot?

Comment: did you try openmp instead of custom threading?

Comment: This is a homework and I cannot use Openmp

Comment: I would suggest to take const reference whenever you can, for example in your lambda: 
[](const ComplexNumber &a, const ComplexNumber &b) { ... }

Comment: I updated the original question with the result from Very Sleepy

Comment: So what does this `ComplexNumber` class look like? Right now question lacks minimal example demonstrating stated problem.

Comment: I updated the question by adding the ComplexNumber class

Comment: `class ComplexNumber {` who wrote that pile of steaming abstraction?  Can you change it?

Comment: The problem was that i used regex to parse the complex numbers from the file, and they were very slow. After replacing them I managed to get the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this:

```
struct ComplexNumber {
    double real; // *maybe* = 0
    double imaginary; // *maybe* = 0

    ComplexNumber( double r, double i ):real(r), imaginary(i) {}

    ComplexNumber() = default;
    ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber &complexNumber) = default;
    ComplexNumber& operator=(const ComplexNumber &complexNumber) = default;

};
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const ComplexNumber &complexNumber);
```

`<<` can be slow, and doesn't need to be a friend.  Stop using accessors (especialy non-inlinable ones) for accessing your fields.

If you really need accessors, at least make them inline and in the header.  But here they are pointless.

I'd also write `operator+` and the like even if I didn't need them, because why not.

```
struct ComplexNumber {
    double real; // *maybe* = 0
    double imaginary; // *maybe* = 0

    ComplexNumber( double r, double i ):real(r), imaginary(i) {}

    ComplexNumber() = default;
    ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber &complexNumber) = default;
    ComplexNumber& operator=(const ComplexNumber &complexNumber) = default;

  ComplexNumber& operator+=( ComplexNumber const& o )& {
    real += o.real;
    imaginary += o.imaginary;
    return *this;
  }
  ComplexNumber& operator-=( ComplexNumber const& o )& {
    real -= o.real;
    imaginary -= o.imaginary;
    return *this;
  }
  ComplexNumber& operator*=( ComplexNumber const& o )& {
    ComplexNumber r{ real*o.real - imaginary*o.imaginary, real*o.imaginary + imaginary*o.real };
    *this = r;
    return *this;
  }

  friend ComplexNumber operator+( ComplexNumber lhs, ComplexNumber const& rhs ) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend ComplexNumber operator-( ComplexNumber lhs, ComplexNumber const& rhs ) {
    lhs -= rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend ComplexNumber operator*( ComplexNumber lhs, ComplexNumber const& rhs ) {
    lhs *= rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
};
```

which is brain-dead boilerplate, but I couldn't justify having a `ComplexNumber` type without at least those.  (I left out `/` because an important decision on how to deal with division by zero remains).

In any case, once we are no longer hiding how data is accessed from the code doing work, the optimzier now has a chance to actually optimize.

Comment: The problem was that i used regex to parse the complex numbers from the file, and they were very slow. After replacing them I managed to get the correct behaviour.